# Does using ConditionalAttribute also remove arguments computation?

Tags: c#, .net, conditional-attribute

I tried the following code:

```
class Magic {
   [Conditional("DEBUG")]
   public static void DoMagic( int stuff )
   {
   }
   public static int ComputeMagic()
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      Magic.DoMagic(Magic.ComputeMagic());
   }
}
```

and it looks like in Release build the exception is not thrown so not only the call to a method marked with `ConditionalAttribute` is removed, but also the parameters computation is eliminated.

Is such behavior guaranteed?

Comment: It would be nice if you accepted an answer here :).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, argument evaluation is removed when `DEBUG` is not defined (which is typical in Release builds).

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#reserved-attributes:

> If the symbol is defined, the call is included; otherwise, the call
> (including evaluation of the parameters of the call) is omitted.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, **everything** is removed. This can be great for avoiding expensive computations that are only relevant for (say) logging, but it means you need to be careful not to remove *necessary* side-effects. For example:

```
Trace(SomethingCritical());
```

is very different to:

```
var result = SomethingCritical();
Trace(result);
```

or in your specific case:

```
DoMagic(ComputeMagic()); // everything here done only if DEBUG symbol defined
```

versus

```
var result = ComputeMagic(); // always done
DoMagic(result); // done only if DEBUG symbol defined
```

From the specification §17.4.2 (emphasis mine):

> If the symbol is defined, the call is included; otherwise, the call (***including evaluation of the receiver and parameters of the call***) is omitted.