# Conditional attribute and calculated arguments for method

Tags: c#, conditional-attribute

I have code like this in my code

```
Debug.WriteLine($@"Operation time: {elapsedMilliseconds}ms");
```

Write line marked with  [Conditional("DEBUG")], that means that calls of this method will be omitted in release.

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static void WriteLine(string message, string category)
{
  TraceInternal.WriteLine(message, category);
}
```

But, will it call string.Format for argument of this method in RELEASE or remove it too?

Answer (score 2):

Found answer here - [Does using ConditionalAttribute also remove arguments computation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935452/does-using-conditionalattribute-also-remove-arguments-computation)

> If the symbol is defined, the call is included; otherwise, the call
>   (including evaluation of the parameters of the call) is omitted.