# Purpose of the () => vs just getting a property directly

Tags: c#

So I am learning more C# and came across this syntax:

```
Log.Info(() => $"Some Text {SomeVariableorProperty}");
```

How does this differ from the following?

```
Log.Info($"Some Text {SomeVariableorProperty}");
```

I know that the () => is basically a delegate but not sure what its purpose is here.

Comment: Which logging package are you using?

Comment: Here is no difference. In another context it may differ

Comment: That basically depends on what `Log` is but I would suspect that in this case it makes no difference. Using the `()=>` syntax you are just creating a new anonymous function that is returning a string (the same string as below).

Comment: Too much flexibility, a `Func<string>` strikes me as overkill.  Look at *all* the overloads of the Info() method, surely it has one that takes a plain string.

Comment: Which package does `Log.Info(...)` come from? You need to check the documentation for the `Log.Info(Func<string> func)` overload.

Comment: I could be wrong but I honestly don't think that does anything, where did you see that first example? because the only reason you'd want to pass a delegate is for a callback, but that doesn't make sense. I can't see any documentation on the Log.Info class that shows the use of a delegate.

Comment: One reason for the first approach is for if it's *expensive* to generate the required string. You're effectively giving the logging system control over if the string generation even occurs - e.g. if info-level messages are excluded from actual logging, etc.

Comment: First one means: *hey log method, use this delegate*. The delegate does nothing but return a string. The 2nd one means: *hey log method, use this string.*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The scenario is:

```
Log.Info(() => $"Some Text {SomeSlowMethod()}");

public static string SomeSlowMethod()
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return "Foo";
}
```

Now... What happens if the logging of `Info` is disabled? Is the `SomeSlowMethod` called? The answer is no! Because the calling of the delegate `() => $"Some Text {SomeSlowMethod()}` is done by `Log.Info()` **if it needs to do it**. Compare it with:

```
Log.Info($"Some Text {SomeSlowMethod()}");
```

Now `SomeSlowMethod()` is always called, and there is the possibility that `Log.Info` will ignore its value.

If you think that `SomeSlowMethod()`s in real case scenarios don't exist, remember that even string composition is "slow" compared to other operations. Simply doing useless `string.Format` (`$"Some Text {SomeVariableorProperty}` is a `string.Format`) is a waste of time. And one of the laws of a good logging library is that if it isn't active it shouldn't slow your application.

To make an interesting comparison, `Debug.Assert()`:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void Assert(bool condition, string message);
```

Here `message` is a `string`, but you see the `[Conditional(...)]`? if `DEBUG` isn't defined at compile time, the C# compiler can remove the whole `Debug.Assert()` method call, and even remove all the methods that are called inside the `Debug.Assert()`, so modifying possible side effects:

```
Debug.Assert(false, Throw());

public static string Throw()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

If `DEBUG` isn't defined (so you are executing a `RELEASE` build), this will be converted to:

```
; // nothing
```

so no `throw` (see for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21935478/613130)). But note that this must be resolved at *compilation* time, while logging libraries are configured at *runtime*.

Answer (score 5):

It means that the `Log.Info` method is expecting a function with the signature `Func<String>`, essentially a parameterless function that will return a string.

Passing `$"Some Text {SomeVariableorProperty}"` directly will fail when building, as this is a `String` and not a function that can be executed. That is - unless the method itself has overloads that accept just a `String`.

If you're in complete control over the code, then completely agree that it's a little odd, I can't see a strong reason for wanting to use a function over a `String`.

The only good use case for this as @KirkLarkin suggests is if the generation of that Log message needs to be done in a lazy manner. You'd probably only need this in an edge case scenario where the creating the actual message to log is an expensive operation. That way if you're call to `Log.Info()` decides it doesn't need to log it (e.g. it's too verbose based on a setting) you can bypass the expensive message generation. As I say though - it'd be rare that you'd come across a situation like this and probably indicates that too much is being logged.

Comment: @bornfromanegg Thanks. I just thought the same and edited the answer same time as you were posting. I've been doing too much JavaScript with no overloading!